# Justifying a trace route path

Tags: networking, routes, ip, packets, traceroute

Im tracerouting a server in Bolivia. Analysing the route closer i can see that it visits the following locations:

```
 1  xxxxxxxx (xxxxxxx)  1.001 ms  1.628 ms  2.126 ms
 2  xxxxxxxx (xxxxxxx)  0.649 ms  0.768 ms  0.757 ms
 3  xxxxxxxx (xxxxxx)  2.348 ms  2.343 ms  1.533 ms
 4  xxxxxxx (xxxxxxxx)  3.340 ms  2.839 ms  3.254 ms
 5  ge-11-0-0.norw-rbr2.eastern.ja.net (146.97.130.249)  3.244 ms  3.332 ms  3.220 ms
 6  ipsw-rbr2.eastern.ja.net (146.97.65.85)  5.537 ms  6.601 ms  7.244 ms
 7  chel-rbr3.eastern.ja.net (146.97.65.65)  7.351 ms  7.665 ms  7.487 ms
 8  lond-rbr1.eastern.ja.net (146.97.65.37)  8.014 ms  7.658 ms  7.993 ms
 9  ae3.lond-sbr4.ja.net (146.97.35.125)  9.938 ms  8.883 ms  8.842 ms
10  ldn-b4-link.telia.net (213.248.84.177)  8.697 ms  8.808 ms  7.351 ms
11  ldn-bb2-link.telia.net (80.91.251.14)  8.786 ms ldn-bb2-link.telia.net (80.91.254.21)  7.889 ms ldn-bb1-link.telia.net (80.91.250.234)  7.834 ms
12  ldn-b5-link.telia.net (80.91.247.92)  17.002 ms ldn-b5-link.telia.net (80.91.247.90)  8.295 ms ldn-b5-link.telia.net (80.91.247.92)  15.368 ms
13  verio-129583-ldn-b5.telia.net (213.248.100.50)  8.660 ms  7.780 ms  7.896 ms
14  ae-4.r22.londen03.uk.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.5.24)  8.433 ms  8.233 ms  7.675 ms
15  as-0.r22.nycmny01.us.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.3.254)  99.876 ms  99.939 ms  99.895 ms
16  ae-0.r23.nycmny01.us.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.3.73)  76.968 ms  87.085 ms  87.389 ms
17  ae-1.r20.asbnva02.us.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.2.9)  82.700 ms  85.264 ms  82.640 ms
18  ae-0.r21.asbnva02.us.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.4.5)  83.869 ms  95.449 ms  84.552 ms
19  ae-2.r20.miamfl02.us.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.2.98)  112.581 ms  135.580 ms  130.857 ms
20  ae-1.r05.miamfl02.us.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.2.185)  121.337 ms ae-  1.r04.miamfl02.us.bb.gin.ntt.net (129.250.2.111)  108.961 ms  108.636 ms
21  xe-0-5-0-7-54.r04.miamfl02.us.ce.gin.ntt.net (157.238.179.50)  114.734 ms xe-0-6-0-7-  56.r05.miamfl02.us.ce.gin.ntt.net (157.238.179.46)  124.485 ms xe-0-5-0-7-  54.r04.miamfl02.us.ce.gin.ntt.net (157.238.179.50)  116.544 ms
22  200.87.252.149 (200.87.252.149)  122.668 ms  113.052 ms LPZ-PEER-01.entelnet.bo (200.87.252.141)  191.274 ms
23  LPZ-PEER-01.entelnet.bo (200.87.252.141)  200.642 ms LPZ-CRS1-01.entelnet.bo (190.129.252.54)  231.495 ms  222.222 ms
24  LPZ-ASR-01.entelnet.bo (200.87.251.14)  220.119 ms  229.793 ms  230.677 ms
25  LPZ-CEoIP-01.entelnet.bo (190.129.252.34)  196.715 ms  196.700 ms  195.552 ms
26  LPZ-CEoIP-01.entelnet.bo (190.129.252.34)  195.561 ms 190.129.125.3 (190.129.125.3)     221.980 ms LPZ-CEoIP-01.entelnet.bo (190.129.252.34)  195.771 ms
27  190.129.125.3 (190.129.125.3)  222.356 ms  224.549 ms LOOPBACK0-CORE-        BGP4.200.75.175.254.MegaLink.com (200.75.175.254)  306.277 ms
28  MegaLink.com (200.75.160.11)  307.680 ms  288.314 ms  355.238 ms
```

I was just wondering as to why it doesn't take a more efficient route rather than travelling around the worlds what seems like twice. Any helpful information would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Could you post your actual traceroute?

Comment: Sure. I thought itd save you guys time locating the IPs

Answer (score -1):

From what I'm looking at, there's nothing unusual about this traceroute.

I don't know where you're getting your locations, but here's how it breaks down:

1-4:  Clearly, unknown.

5-9:  [JaNet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JANET) is a UK network.

10-13: Clearly still in London.

14: londen probably means LondEn, or London, England

15-16:  Trans-Atlantic jump to NYC, Manhattan, in NY

17-18:  Somewhere in VA (Virginia)

19-21:  Miami, FL (Florida)

22(ish)-26: Bouncing around in LaPaz

27: ?

28: Target Webserver

Comment: @FredBones - GeoBytes is intended to identify Hosts on the network edge, not routers in the core.  It doesn't actually know where anything is, it just uses data from webservers to build a map of likelihood.  But the IP of the routers is not layed out along the same map.